# Retrieve URL from uploaded image on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have uploaded an image to Firebase storage, but when I try to retrieve the URL, I get "uploaded_image.ref is not a function" .....

HTML

```
<form>
<input id="select_Image" type="file" required>
<button type="submit">Upload Image</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
let image_url = ""; 

function uploadImage {

  const image = input_image.files[0];
  const path = storage.ref("imagefolder/" + image.name);

  const uploaded_image = path.put(image);
  const the_url = uploaded_image.ref().getDownloadURL();

  image_url = the_url; 
  alert(image_url);

}
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `uploaded_image` doesn't have a method called `ref()`.  What are you expecting that's different?  Have you gone through the documentation for getting download URLs?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `put()` method and the `getDownloadURL()` method need to call the server to do their work. For that reason they return a promise, and you have to wait for that promise to complete to get their results.

In addition, you can only get the download URL for an image, after it's been uploaded. So you should only call `getDownloadURL()` once the `put()` has completed.

In code that'd look something like this:

```
function uploadImage {
  const image = input_image.files[0];
  const path = storage.ref("imagefolder/" + image.name);

  path.put(image).then(function() {
    path.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
      alert(url);
    }
  }
}
```

As said in the comments, the `downloadUrl` is only usable **inside** the callback. If you use it elsewhere it may not have the value you want it to have. So any code that requires the download URL should be inside the callback, or be called from there.

Also see:

- [Image from Cloud Storage is not redendring in .map list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836115/image-from-cloud-storage-is-not-redendring-in-map-list/52836403#52836403)
- [Firebase web: upload multiple files to Storage an then download their URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207412/firebase-web-upload-multiple-files-to-storage-an-then-download-their-urls/60210254#60210254)
- [Show a modal after images are uploaded with JS and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60236053/show-a-modal-after-images-are-uploaded-with-js-and-firebase/60240358#60240358)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the `.put()` function is async, so you need to handle the callback and do your work inside that function instead.  You could do this with async, await, or just use a closure:

```
const uploaded_image = path.put(image).then((snapshot) => {
     alert("Done!");
   });
```

Also, according to [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files), you don't actually need the server to tell you the URL because you're supposed to construct it yourself.